# Spring Boot: StackOverflowError HttpServletRequestWrapper getUserPrincipal

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, stack-overflow, waffle, embedded-tomcat

in our production log we got the following very long stack traces:

```
java.lang.StackOverflowError: null
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequestWrapper.getUserPrincipal(HttpServletRequestWrapper.java:199) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar!/:4.0.FR]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequestWrapper.getUserPrincipal(HttpServletRequestWrapper.java:199) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar!/:4.0.FR]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequestWrapper.getUserPrincipal(HttpServletRequestWrapper.java:199) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar!/:4.0.FR]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequestWrapper.getUserPrincipal(HttpServletRequestWrapper.java:199) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar!/:4.0.FR]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequestWrapper.getUserPrincipal(HttpServletRequestWrapper.java:199) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar!/:4.0.FR]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequestWrapper.getUserPrincipal(HttpServletRequestWrapper.java:199) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar!/:4.0.FR]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequestWrapper.getUserPrincipal(HttpServletRequestWrapper.java:199) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar!/:4.0.FR]
...
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.getUsernameForRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1160) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.publishRequestHandledEvent(FrameworkServlet.java:1145) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1023) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:626) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar!/:4.0.FR]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:733) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar!/:4.0.FR]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar!/:9.0.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar!/:9.0.37]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:103) ~[spring-web-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar!/:9.0.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar!/:9.0.37]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:113) ~[spring-web-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar!/:9.0.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar!/:9.0.37]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:103) ~[spring-web-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar!/:9.0.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar!/:9.0.37]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:103) ~[spring-web-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar!/:9.0.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar!/:9.0.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:712) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar!/:9.0.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInclude(ApplicationDispatcher.java:580) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar!/:9.0.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.include(ApplicationDispatcher.java:516) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar!/:9.0.37]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:163) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:316) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1373) ~...
```

and

```
java.lang.StackOverflowError: null
    at javax.servlet.ServletRequestWrapper.getAsyncContext(ServletRequestWrapper.java:435) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.44.jar!/:4.0.FR]
```

Unfortunately i can't reproduce this behaviour in local or test.
In the stacktraces is no reference to our application code.
So maybe it's a config issue with spring boot in combination with embedded tomcat and waffle?
Currently we are using Spring Boot 2.4.4 and Java 11 in combination with Angular 10.

The exceptions also seems not to be caused directly by user interactions (checked the access log).
I already tried different versions of the frameworks with no success.

Any ideas?

Comment: If you are using Spring Boot 2.4.4 uses tomcat 9.0.44 yours is 9.0.37 so it looks like you have overridden versions that are used with Spring Boot, the same for Spring itself normally it used 5.3.x you are on 5.2. So it appears as if you are managing things yourself. I would suggest leaving that management to Spring Boot instead of doing your own. Which is probably the cause of this as well (could be a bug in that version of tomcat or something like that). Also make sure that you are using the exact same JDK locally and in prod even that can make a difference.

Comment: thanks for the reply.This was not the problem. I just updated Spring Boot. But copied the log from the old version. The java version is also in every environment the same.